# Object doesn't fly right

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, cocos2d-iphone-3

I am a new programmer in cocos2D and I tried to do the tutorial https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/creating-two-levels/
but my Object just fly down on the ground and not right... I don't know what wrong is.
here is my Code:

```
- (void)launchFire {
    // loads the Penguin.ccb we have set up in Spritebuilder
    CCNode* fireBall = [CCBReader load:@"Fireball"];
    // position the penguin at the bowl of the catapult
    fireBall.position = ccpAdd(_block.position, ccp(18, 50));

    CCLOG(@"Block Position: \nX:%.2f\nY:%.2f",_block.position.x,_block.position.y);
    CCLOG(@"Fireball Position: \nX:%.2f\nY:%.2f",fireBall.position.x,fireBall.position.y);
    // add the penguin to the physicsNode of this scene (because it has physics enabled)
    [_physicsNode addChild:fireBall];

    // manually create & apply a force to launch the penguin
    CGPoint launchDirection = ccp(1, 0);
    CGPoint force = ccpMult(launchDirection, 8000);
    [fireBall.physicsBody applyForce:force];        
}
```

I used the Variable Fireball and not Pinguin...
[image: Fireball Physics config]

If you can help me, many many Thanks.

Comment: CGPoint launchDirection = ccp(1, 0);  <-- this creates a force on the X axis only, try ccp(1, 1) for a 45° angle trajectory.

Comment: nothing change still fly down ...
I tried some other physics body functions but nothing happen...

Comment: Try applyImpulse or a greater force than 8000. Check that gravity isn't set too high (0, -10 should suffice for gravity).

Comment: just vertical down...
Its awful, ...
no impulse help, nothing,... I think the Physik body doenst work...